# CSS border-radius contain inner elements as well

Tags: css

I have two panel with border-radius properties applied to it. Both panels have elements inside them with there own background colours and borders. Both panels are scrollable. In the case of the first panel as the div is scrolled the background colours and borders accept the border radius of the container as the edge, whereas in the second panel the borders and background colours of the inner elements overlap the corners with their straight edges. Why?

The behaving panel ::

```
#coursepack .corecol .extention .dirpanel {
    background-color:#222;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:10px;
    height:322px;
    width:304px;
    border:1px solid #AAA;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The misbehaving panel ::

```
#coursepanel .opsextention {
    position:absolute;
    width:320px;
    height:410px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:10px;
    z-index:2;
    opacity:0.80;
    left:358px;
    top:20px;
    background-color:#222;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #FFF;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #FFF;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Solve a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3V8T8/5/ notice the borders penetrating the corners

Here is a fiddle showing both. The second one shows working rounded corners, but I see not what the difference is http://jsfiddle.net/3V8T8/10/

Comment: Can you provide the html and/or ideally a working example.

Comment: Heres a fiddle showing the one that does not work. Notice the borders as they penetrate the corners of the container http://jsfiddle.net/3V8T8/5/

Comment: Here's another fiddle showing both http://jsfiddle.net/3V8T8/10/

Comment: I've asked the same question here on stack overflow. Yet to find a suitable answer. This appears to be an oversight that happens across all browsers.

Comment: what browser and version? I just tested it on FF 3 Mac and looks good.

Comment: @Chris Sobolewski - Agreed, but I don't see why it works in one place and not another. Check out the second FIDDLE that I put up where you can see both http://jsfiddle.net/3V8T8/10/

Comment: I'm testing FF, Chrome and Safari and have it functioning in all for one panel and none for the second

Comment: @Robin I can see the blue highlight squares breaking out of the corner of the second one, though! Will have to try it on some more modern browsers when I get home...

Comment: Chrome and Firefox, the blue boxes stay inside

Comment: I can't see any problem. Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height and line height from the .opsextention .teetime class then use padding:10px 25px 10px 25px to space it out and that grey line does not go outside the corner